# app.post don't work from Firebase Database at REACT JS (error "=>")

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

index.js

```
`API routes`
`This is where I have the problem "=>"`
app.post('/payments/create', async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total, 
    currency: 'usd',
  });
 
  `OK - Created`
  response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});
```

Error Message;

Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

"=> (underlined)"

Comment: Looks like you're using an old node version that doesn't support arrow functions?

Comment: So how can I update the version.

Comment: Go here: https://nodejs.org/ But type this into a terminal first: `node -v` what does it say?

Comment: I did what you said, i wrote "node -v" the on terminal. Me versions is v12.16.1
After, i updated the node. Now "node-v" -> v15.6.0

but still not working! :((       "=>" is underline

Comment: I still could not my friend. I need help @ChrisG

Comment: Maybe your IDE is the problem, which one do you use? You say it's underlined. What happens if you ignore the "error" and simply run the code with node?

Comment: i'm using VS Code. 
The code I want to run-->      "firebase deploy --only functions"
Error-->          "functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1"

Comment: https://youtu.be/RDV3Z1KCBvo?t=25437   this is proje @ChrisG

Comment: You should have configuration files in your project folder, like `eslint` or `babel-eslint`. That's where you tell VS Code what version of JavaScript you're using, and how it checks your code. The error you describe is usually caused by that, because arrow functions are an ES6 feature.